# Facebook SDK remove my R.java

Tags: android, facebook

I'm try to working with FaceBook SDK but every time got error something.. 1 month ago I was running one project correctly but I can' t working.

I add Facebook SDK my project,
[image]

It's added normally

[image]

When I click to OK button, It's remove my R.java file and It's never come back.

[image]

***Please see gen folder.***

I'm try to clean, remove second android-support library vs. vs.. After the error If I remove Facebook SDK, nothing change. I got error continue.

[image]

How can I solve this issue? I try to backup R.java and add in the gen folder after FB library but It's again removed.

Thanks for help.

Comment: It says Jar Mismatch in the error box. Can you postcomplete Error from the Error log tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R.java is a generated file. You should not modify or delete the file. Check to see the build path is correct or not by

```
Right Click on Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path
```

Check whether all the `jar` files are imported or not. In third image, `android-support-library.jar` is missing. Please add that file using `Add Jars` button. `Clean` the Project once and run it. It should work.

Comment: I'm checking my build path but I think everything correct. I remove android-support-library and add again. etc. And I use both of facebook lib and my project lib same file. My build path looks like a this

(www.dedikoducoplugu.com/7.png)

Comment: I found the problem. What is your target version and Minimum version in `AndroidManifest.xml`. `android:Theme.Holo.Light` supports from API Level 11 in `strings.xml`. Please add the content of `AndroidManifest.xml`. Problem is there only.

Comment: I can't believe that.. You are awesome! Thank you! Problem is solved.. I'm so happy :) Thank you again :)

Answer (score 3):

In the third screenshot I can see a problem in `android-support-library.jar`. 
Copy `android-support-v4.jar` from the `libs` folder of your project to the Facebook project. You should use equal versions of the library.

Comment: I change android-support-library.jar after that It's change. But R.java not exist.

(www.dedikoducoplugu.com/5.png)

(www.dedikoducoplugu.com/6.png)